# How to have an HTML input that spans multiple lines?

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I'm trying to create a user experience that looks like this:

[image]

Basically, there is a `<span>` of non-editable text followed by a textarea/input and some other non-editable `<span>s`. A simple textarea/input poses no problem when the length of the gap is short, but when it's long, the layout gets pretty awkward. I've looked into `contentEditable`, but I'm not sure if it's what I need (I've also read several [posts](https://medium.com/content-uneditable/contenteditable-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-261a38555e9c) suggesting it's evil).

Do I have any other options?

Comment: I think contentEditable is a good option. You can skin it and make it look like an input tag. Most of the inline editors use it: https://yabwe.github.io/medium-editor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the `contentEditable` property can help you. Have a look here https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/prop_html_contenteditable.asp

There is a tipical example
 https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_body_contenteditable

You may switch on an editable mode for a span or inline div, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to have an input as you're suggesting.

If you are having an issue with the layout at different sizes, perhaps look into [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) with CSS, which will allow you to alter the layout at different viewport sizes.

It might be easier for you to use a framework like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to help you layout your web page, although in my opinion frameworks like bootstrap can start to interfere with a custom design, but this will only be a problem when you are a little more experienced.